# Background filter for dropdown

Tags: html, css

The dropdown opens when elements of navbar are hovered. I want the background picture in hero div as well as rest of the body below navbar to be blurred. I tried using backdrop filter but its working. I included backdrop filter in sub-menu class but it has no effect on the image below it. I tried overlay but not exactly sure how to use it.

```css
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding-left: 1.1rem;
}

.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.nav-list>li>a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff2a00;
  height: 3.6px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.nav-list>li>a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 6.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  width: 82.5rem;
  height: 35rem;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
}

.nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 6.5rem;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hero>img {
  position: relative;
  top: 6.3rem;
  z-index:-1;
  left: 4.5rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">Test 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="%">Test 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="hero">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" style="height: 690px;width: 1300px;">
</div>
```

Comment: for me you need JS for this .... on mouse event or jQuery mouseover, mouseout ... and then add css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The CSS way:

I think you are looking for a css ruleset like this:

```
nav:has(a:hover) ~ * {
  filter: blur(1.5rem);
}
```

Setting `filter: blur(1.5rem);` to the next siblings of the `<nav>` element ***when*** having an anchor on `:hover`.

But it's using `:has()` that is not still well supported (Firefox still missing).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

> The functional :has() CSS pseudo-class represents an element if any of
> the relative selectors that are passed as an argument match at least
> one element when anchored against this element. This pseudo-class
> presents a way of selecting a parent element or a previous sibling
> element with respect to a reference element by taking a relative
> selector list as an argument.

## The Javascript way:

Since via css there are some limits, you can decide to use js to listen for both the `mouseover` and the `mouseleave` events on each anchor in the `.navbar` that will toggle the `blur` class. Such class has a css rule like the one used before but with the `.blur` selector:

```
const toggleBlur = (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('nav ~ *')
    .forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('blur'));
};

const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-list li a');

anchors.forEach(anchor => anchor.addEventListener('mouseover', toggleBlur));
anchors.forEach(anchor => anchor.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleBlur));
```

## The demo:

Here the demo with your code and the addition explained above:

```js
const toggleBlur = (event) => {      
  //select all the next siblings of <nav> to be blurred
  document.querySelectorAll('nav ~ *')
    .forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('blur'));
};

function toggleStyleStrategy(btn){  
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-list li a');
  
  if(btn.dataset.current == 'js'){
    removeEventListeners(anchors, toggleBlur);
    btn.dataset.current = 'css';
    btn.textContent = 'Style with JS';
  }else{    
    addEventListeners(anchors, toggleBlur);
    btn.dataset.current = 'js';
    btn.textContent = 'Style with CSS';
  }
}

function addEventListeners(anchors, action){    
  anchors.forEach(a => a.addEventListener('mouseover', action));
  anchors.forEach(a => a.addEventListener('mouseleave', action));
}

function removeEventListeners(anchors, action){
  anchors.forEach(a => a.removeEventListener('mouseover', action));
  anchors.forEach(a => a.removeEventListener('mouseleave', action));
}
```

```css
.bottom{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: solid 4px yellow;
}

.bottom button{
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer; 
  font-size: 2rem;
}

/*
this same rule is splitted with the 2 different selectors
instead of using the , because in firefox where the :has
is not supported, the rule won't trigger at all even if
the .blur selector was supposed to be valid. The whole
rule gets discarded
*/
.blur {
  filter: blur(1.5rem);
}

nav:has(a:hover) ~ * {
  filter: blur(1.5rem);
}

nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding-left: 1.1rem;
}

.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list > li > a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.nav-list > li > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff2a00;
  height: 3.6px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.nav-list > li > a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 6.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  width: 82.5rem;
  height: 35rem;
  z-index: 100;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 6.5rem;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hero{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid;
}

.hero > img {
  position: relative;
  /*changed the positioning with padding*/
  padding-top: 6.3rem;
  padding-left: 4.5rem;
  z-index:-1;
  
  /*commented the sizing on inline style and set something more friendly*/
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.furthercontent{
  border:solid 4px purple;
  display: block;
  height: 10ch;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 3rem 3em;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
  <button
    onclick="toggleStyleStrategy(this);"
    data-current="css">Style with JS</button>
</div>

<!-- the navbar that will trigger the blur -->
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">Test 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="%">Test 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- the first of the next following siblings that will be blurred -->
<div class="hero">
  <img
    src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt=""
    style="/*height: 690px;width: 1300px;*/">
</div>

<div class="furthercontent">
  This is further content that will be subject to blur like the .hero element when a link of the navbar will be on :hover
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. This is working but there's a problem. There are more elements below hero that I didn't include in the code to keep it simple. But as per your code, blur is applied only to hero. If a user scrolls while the blur is on, all elements below hero will be without blur and this is not good. Is there any way yo solve this? Right now I applied blur to all  divs below hero and its working. but is there a better way

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. To better highlight the scenario, I added another sibling following the `.hero` div. I also changed the css property set on the `<img>` from `top` to `padding-top` so that the sibling will be drawn next to it following the flow layout. Both gets blurred while you are hovering a link in the navbar. Can you please better explain the issue. Maybe you meant a better selector could be used. Yes maybe. You could have a unique container to blur; a 100vw/100vh opacity layer just below the navbar popups; or something like `:not(nav)` .. but how much difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can delegate an event handler to body. Then add a blur class to the BODY if its a link under nav-list.

Then in CSS, just dictate what you want to blur like this:

```
.blur .hero{}
```

```js
let _body = document.body;

_body.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if (el.closest(".nav-list")) {
    _body.classList.add("blur")
  } else {
    _body.classList.remove("blur")
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding-left: 1.1rem;
}

.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.nav-list>li>a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff2a00;
  height: 3.6px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.nav-list>li>a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 6.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  width: 82.5rem;
  height: 35rem;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
}

.nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 6.5rem;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hero>img {
  position: relative;
  top: 6.3rem;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 4.5rem;
}

.blur .hero {
  filter: blur(10px)
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">Test 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="%">Test 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="hero">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" style="height: 690px;width: 1300px;">
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. This is working but there's a problem. There are more elements below hero that I didn't include in the code to keep it simple. But as per your code, blur is applied only to hero. If a user scrolls while the blur is on, all elements below hero will be without blur and this is not good. Is there any way yo solve this? Right now I applied blur to all  divs below hero and its working. but is there a better way